# XSLT output to HTML

Tags: xml, xslt

In my XSLT file, I have the following:

```
<input type="button" value= <xsl:value-of select="name">>
```

It's an error as it violates XML rule.

What I actually want is having a value from an XML file assigned to 'value' parameter in the HTML output. How do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not at all necessary to use `xsl:element`; I don't know why so many people are suggesting it.  This will work:

```
<input type="button">
   <xsl:attribute name="value">
      <xsl:value-of name="name"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
</input>
```

...but even better is using an attribute value template:

```
<input type="button" value="{name}"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<xsl:element name="input">
<xsl:attribute name="type">button</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="value" select="name">
</xsl:element>
```

Excellent reference to [HTML/XSL](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tiphtml.html)

Answer (score 5):

```
value="{name}"
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates

EDIT: Changed {$name} to {name}

Comment: @VladV that a variable setup ... he is using `value-of`

Comment: I am not sure it works guys me I always use the `xsl:attribute`

Answer (score 3):

you shoud do something like this

```
<xsl:element name="a"><xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="url" /></xsl:attribute> <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute></xsl:element>
```

more reference on [xsl:attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/el_attribute.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `<xsl:element>` is the way to go here, but you got your parsing error because you didn't close out the `<xsl:value-of select="name" />` element. Notice the `/` at the end; all XML elements need closure, unlike HTML.